# Sign In page using SQL SERVER, JAVA, Servlets, Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets, sql-server-2014-express

Here is my code, it is connecting to database, in the console I could see the msg "connected" but the problem is after giving the user credentials it is not navigating to the next page(welcome.jsp) and it just shows a msg that "username or password error" could someone help me out

**LoginServlet.java**

```
package com.amzi.servlets;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String n=request.getParameter("username");
        String p=request.getParameter("userpass");
        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://WMDENTW1\\SQLEXPRESS:1433;" + 
                    "database=FullTextDB;" + 
                    "user=root;" + 
                    "password=root123"; 
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl); 
            System.out.println("Connected.");
            PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("select User, Password from dbo.AdminLogin where User=? and Password=?");  
            pst.setString(1, n);  
            pst.setString(2, p);  

            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();  
            if (rs.next()) {
                out.println("page opened");
                RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("WebContent/welcome.jsp");  
                rd.forward(request,response);  
            } else {
                out.print("<p style=\"color:red\">Sorry username or password error</p>");  
                RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");  
                rd.include(request,response);  
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        } 
        out.close();
    }
}
```

**index.JSP**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Login Application</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="LoginServlet" method="post">
        <fieldset style="width: 300px">
            <legend> Login to App </legend>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>User ID</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="username" required="required" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password</td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="userpass" required="required" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Welcome.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"> <title>Welcome <%=session.getAttribute("name")%></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Login successful!!!</h3>
    <h4>        Hello,      <%=session.getAttribute("name")%></h4>
</body>
</html>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"     version="2.5">  <servlet>       <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>      <servlet-class>com.amzi.servlets.LoginServlet</servlet-class>   </servlet>  <servlet-mapping>       <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>      <url-pattern>/LoginServlet</url-pattern>    </servlet-mapping>  <welcome-file-list>         <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: What are you writing to the response output stream as well as forwarding to a JSP? Do one or the other, not both!

Comment: hey! thanks for the reply but I did not understand what you said, could you please mention it clearly!!

Answer (score 0):

In response your your request to clarify my comment, instead I shall write it as an answer.

IN your `doPost` method, you have this line:

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
```

After that, you use `out` to write directly to the response, such as in these lines:

```
out.println("page opened");
```

and

```
out.print("<p style=\"color:red\">Sorry username or password error</p>");
```

However, you then go and forward to a JSP:

```
RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("WebContent/welcome.jsp");  
rd.forward(request,response);
```

But that does the same thing - after processing the JSP it sends the result to the response PrintWriter, just have you have done.

You really shouldn't do both. Just use the JSPs.

Secondly, your message 'username or password error' indicates that the query returned no rows, so the username/password you used is probably wrong. I can't see anything wrong with the JDBC code or query.

Comment: yeah, what you said is correct but still I can use both out and request dispatcher, because the out statement just act as print statement. The database connection is perfect and the columns are (User, Password) and the columns has inserted values like (admin, admin123) but still I couldn't see the welcome screen.  Does my code is missing somewhere or do you have any other idea..?

Comment: Thanks for the help I figure it out what was the mistake, as I have defined the User as primary key in the database  it should be written as [User] if you want to access that column.

Comment: Strange, non-standard Microsoftism! AFAIK, no other RDBMS requires such syntax.